# C# DataView Filter expression DateTime format

Tags: c#, date, datagridview, filter, dataview

I'm defining a filter on a DataGridView on a DateTime column as follow:

```
BindingSource.Filter = "Column = '2016-05-26'"
```

Obviously the equality is not correct as the Column is expressed with the timestamp. 
Then, I would like to convert the datetime during the evaluation and write it as:

```
BindingSource.Filter = "convert(Date, [Column]) = '2016-05-26'
```

But it doesn't work?

I would like to avoid to write:

```
    BindingSource.Filter = "Column > '2016-05-25' AND  Column < '2016-05-25'"
```

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks a lot